# Adding string to combobox java

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I am trying to add multiple items to a java combobox, however mine only displays the first one in the list. Any help? This is for my own project, where the user will be able to select a recent image from the drop down list, and it will open. In the end it will be like a paint application with a drop down menu.

```
public class ComboBoxExample extends JFrame 
implements ItemListener {

private JLabel display;  
private JComboBox<String> box;
private String[] distros;


public ComboBoxExample() {

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    String path = "."; 

    String files;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
    {

     if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
     {
     String files1 = listOfFiles[i].getName();
     System.out.println(files1);

    distros = new String[] {files1};

    Container pane = getContentPane();
    GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
    pane.setLayout(gl);        

    box = new JComboBox<>(distros);
    box.addItemListener(this);

    display = new JLabel("");

    gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(box,
                    GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                    GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                    GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(20)
            .addComponent(display)
    );

    gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
            .addComponent(box, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                    GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                    GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(display)
    );

    pack();

    setTitle("JComboBox");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);}}

}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        display.setText(e.getItem().toString());
    }
}    

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ComboBoxExample ex = new ComboBoxExample();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You should consider not implementing the Listener interface and instead using an anonymous nested class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the whole guide over and over again for each file. Thus you only get one string in the box. I'd suggest you pull your initialization method apart into several smaller methods. This will help you to understand what's actually going on.